# Closure of the set of fredholm perturbation

Tags: spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two unital Banach algebras and $T\colon A\to B$ an homomorphism  of Banach algebras. Let denote the set of  Fredholm perturbation elements in $A$, i.e.

$\operatorname{Ft}:=\{r\in A:T(a+r)\mbox{ is invertible in }B \mbox{ iff }T(a) \mbox{ is invertible in }B\}$.

I NEED a clear answer for this questions :

Why $\operatorname{Ft}$ is closed?

Please help me.